# Why is Babel not transpiling my React JSX?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I have a Node JS web app that I've recently decided to add ReactJS to. I can use regular React, but using JSX throws an `unexpected token <` error as Babel doesn't seem to be transpiling it.

I have Babel 7 installed, and have been using it on this project for a while.

I added `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"` and `"@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx"` to my `package.json`, and listed them in my .babelrc file.

I tried adding `type='text/babel'` to the script link but the file didn't even run then.

I know the React code is valid as it's just dummy-code I pulled directly off the React website to test that it's working.

I'm not sure what else I need to do to get Babel to transpile the JSX.

Comment: Adding `type="text/babel"` to a script tag is indeed a dead end unless you're running Babel in the browser. So how are you running Babel in the first place?

Comment: @AKX yeah I didn't think it was the right way to go, but I thought I'd try it just in case. Babel is running on the server

Comment: Sure, but how are you running babel? What's in that script tag, etc.? Doesn't sound like you're using a bundler?

Comment: Oh I see, the script is `babel-node src/index.js` (I'm not using a budler). As I said, I've had no issues with babel so far and have been using it for a while now.

Comment: Right, so that's only running your server code through Babel. You need to also transpile the client-side React code with something, maybe see https://parceljs.org/ :)

Comment: Ahh, that seems so obvious now. Thanks